# Refresh ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have a view pager which I need to refresh it's components which are three fragments.
I want to remove the views and adding new views 
The setadapter method throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Although I remove all views from the pager before setting the new adapter

```
viewPager.removeAllViews();
viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

The Adapter code is as follows

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
SettingRTL settingRTL = new SettingRTL();
private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"News", "Articles", "Reports"};
private String tabTitlesA[] = new String[]{"الأخبار", "المقالات", "التقارير"};

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return PromosFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
        case 1:
            return ArticlesFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
        case 2:
            return OtherFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (settingRTL.getCurrentLang().equals("العربية")) {
        return tabTitlesA[position];
    }
    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to override in your SampleFragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override  **viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()** inside your Fragment.
and then do the needful to create newInstance of Fragment/Activity. whenever the page got changed you can perform your operation for creating new instance of Fragment.